# ProtoBuf - Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, protobuf-net, service-fabric-stateful, protobuf-csharp-port

I am looking at replacing the default serializer for RPC in ASF. This involves implementing a few interfaces, one of which is passed between services communicating via RPC

```
 public interface IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody
  {
    void Set(object response);

    object Get(Type paramType);
  }
```

As the implementation needs to be serializable, the obvious ProtoBuf implementation is something like

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class ProtoBufRemotingResponseBody : IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public void Set(object response)
        {
            Value = response;
        }

        public object Get(Type paramType)
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this fails miserably with

> No serializer defined for type: System.Object

Is there a workaround here? System.Object has no contract, but the OOTB `DataContract` serializer can, as can [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) [here](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/181), but these are not schematized which creates versioning headaches when using [reliable collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections). I have tried using a common base type, but Value can be `IEnumerable<T>` or `T` etc.

Can anyone help?
Thanks,
KH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, protobuf-net does not have good support for `object`, except via some messy hacks. The simplest to try (just to see if it works for your scenario) is to find the "dynamic types" flag on that proto-member attribute and set it to true. This library-specific hack burns some type metadata into to data to allow it to work with unknown types, but it is far from perfect.

The "better" fix here would involve me finding the time to implement the "any" feature (added to the Google library relatively recently, around the time of proto3 IIRC). This works broadly similarly, but would be implemented in a cross-library way.

Comment: Hey Marc, much appreciation for your response. I actually tried that already and received the error ```'Dynamic type is not a contract-type: List`1'```.

Comment: @KnowHoper yeah, there are some pretty key differences between lists and single objects. Even in proto3 terms this is the important difference between `repeated Any` and `optional Any`; I don't have any easy fixes for that. I could possibly *make* `List<T>` work with the dynamic type feature, but it would be trivial, and I can't offer you that today. If you can unpick your data and switch to `List<object>` it might help - but I haven't checked!

Comment: Ok Marc, thanks a lot for your responses. I have a few other avenues to explore. All the best.

Comment: @KnowHoper do you have a solution for this?